# Compare differences in installed windows 2012 server OS on 2 different servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, window-server-2012

**Background**: We host/run our enterprise application. Application has specific hardware dependency,so its not possible to run on virtual environments.

***Problem***: We have couple of servers with same hardware Dell R730 and windows 2012 R2 installed. Same version of hardware drivers are installed. However one machine, we are seeing memory leak compared to other one which is running without any issues.

**Tried so Far:**

- We ran through same inputs, and still application on one machine works fine other has memory leak.
- Same version of the application is running with identical configuration files.
- Features & server roles are same across these machines.
- Windows updates installed on both machines are same.
- Windows OS - build version is matching across these machines.
- Third party applications installed across these machines are same with identical version & build numbers.
- Both servers live in same network (sub domain).

**Consideration**

- We are checking/debugging our application code for any pointers on memory leaks observed.

**Question:**

Other than windows updates and installed third party applications, arethere any other ways to check differences in installed windows OS across these machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a registry diff-tool on registries of the two machines.

I dealt with a similar issue on 2 machines with different behavior that were under the same Group Policy. The registry issue highlighted some areas that our GP rules were missing.

[RegShot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) is a nice tool for this purpose.

Comment: Eventually we found that handles are being leaked at the process/application level. Though it's strange only a particular generation of server has identified this problem. We are fixing these handle leaks at application level. Thanks for the help/support .